# When adding cache to my longest increasing subsequence solution, answer is not correct?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence

For test case

```
input: [5, 4, 19, 5, 7, 12]; output: 4
```

Without the cache, I am able to output 4 correctly.

```
var lengthOfLIS = function (ns) {
  if (ns.length === 1) return 1;

  const prev_i = -1;
  const curr_i = 0;
  const res = 0;
  return recur(ns, prev_i, curr_i, res);
};

// good
var recur = function (ns, prev_i, curr_i, res) {
  //
  if (curr_i >= ns.length) {
    return res;
  }

  // take
  let out_1 = 0;
  if (prev_i === -1) {
    out_1 = recur(ns, curr_i, curr_i + 1, res + 1);
  } else if (ns[curr_i] > ns[prev_i]) {
    out_1 = recur(ns, curr_i, curr_i + 1, res + 1);
  } else if (ns[curr_i] <= ns[prev_i]) {
    out_1 = res;
  }

  // !take
  let out_2 = 0;
  out_2 = recur(ns, prev_i, curr_i + 1, res);

  const max = Math.max(out_1, out_2);
  return max;
};
```

When I adding cache to it, my output is 3.

```
var recur = function (dp, ns, prev_i, curr_i, res) {
  //
  if (curr_i >= ns.length) {
    return res;
  }

  if (prev_i !== -1 && dp[prev_i + 1][curr_i + 1] !== undefined) {
    return dp[prev_i + 1][curr_i + 1];
  }

  // take
  let out_1 = 0;
  if (prev_i === -1) {
    out_1 = recur(dp, ns, curr_i, curr_i + 1, res + 1);
  } else if (ns[curr_i] > ns[prev_i]) {
    out_1 = recur(dp, ns, curr_i, curr_i + 1, res + 1);
  } else if (ns[curr_i] <= ns[prev_i]) {
    out_1 = res;
  }

  // !take
  let out_2 = 0;
  out_2 = recur(dp, ns, prev_i, curr_i + 1, res);

  const max = Math.max(out_1, out_2);
  dp[prev_i + 1][curr_i + 1] = max;
  return max;
};

var lengthOfLIS = function (ns) {
  if (ns.length === 1) return 1;

  const dp = Array(ns.length + 1)
    .fill(undefined)
    .map((_, i) => {
      return Array(ns.length + 1).fill(undefined);
    });

  const prev_i = -1;
  const curr_i = 0;
  const res = 0;
  return recur(dp, ns, prev_i, curr_i, res);
};
```

Could someone point out any mistake I made? I am trying to use debugger to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this kind of problem by comparing the cached result with the uncached result and logging differences.

The problem is that the result of this function depends on the values of prev_i, curr_i, and res.  However, your cache only depends on values of prev_i and curr_i so does not have enough information to predict the correct output.